# YConnectとPassportを使用したログイン機能実装について

Tags: node.js, oauth

Yahoo!JAPANが提供する外部認証機能でYConnectというものがあり
Node.js+Express+Passport+Yconnectを使用したログイン機能の実装をしようと思っています。

下記のサイトで、YConnectの実装方法の一部が書かれています。
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-yj

ただ、上記のサイトの記述だけでは実装できず
下記のTwitterやFacebookやGoogleの外部認証の場合のように

```
var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
```

というように、Strategyのrequireをする必要があるかと思います。

また、callbackURLにアクセスした際に、下記のように
authenticateの後、'twitter'というような名前を書いていかないといけないかと思います。

```
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback',
  passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

ただ、YConnectにはStrategyが存在せず(?)、
Strategyがない場合にどのようにログイン機能を実装すれば良いのか分からず、困っています。
どうやったら実装できますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まずは、[実装例](https://github.com/Lewuathe/passport-yj/blob/master/examples/login/app.js)の該当する箇所を参考にするのがよいと思います。

```
require('passport-yj').YJStrategy;
```

とありますね。